# Trouble iterating through class members in PHP

Tags: php, class, oop, methods

I am trying to write a method which will allow me to iterate through all memebers of the following class:

```
class CrmProfile extends Profile {
 /* Members */
 private $crmType;
 private $crmUrl;
 private $adminPath;
 private $transactionUrl;
 private $membershipUrl;
 private $apiLoginId;
 private $transactionKey;
 private $crmUsername;
 private $crmTestPid;
 private $crmTestSid;
 private $crmTestCc;

 /* Methods */


}

I have functions such as:

public function getCrmType() {
    return $this->crmType;
}
```

But for the project I am working on, I will need to get the values of ALL members in the class through iteration (likely a for, or foreach loop).

Is there an ideal or accepted way to do this, without having to pass a parameter to a generalized "get()" function?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

return an array with all the values(then use foreach on the array) make it a hash array so you can keep the names intact.